# Where is my minecraft mod folder on windows?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have recently downloaded several mods and to install them it says simply put them in your mod folder under your .minecraft folder but, I simply cannot find it! Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Press Windows Key + R, type %appdata%, your .minecraft folder should be within that folder